# centralized logging when clients have an intermittent connection

Tags: logging

I'm working on a project where we'd like to monitor remote embedded clients running Ubuntu Trusty.  We are planning to start by just centralizing `critical` and `error` log messages on one cloud server.

Our client boxes are often deployed in "challenging" conditions though where network connectivity may be dropped for days, but the box is expected to continue operating.  What services could handle these network failures?  `rsyslog` seems promising but are there alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, rsyslog should work perfectly well, however, you could also use Splunk, OpenNMS, or even Nagios with NRPE or SNMP to send alerts.